# C# + WebDriver PageFactory + Nunit 3 Parallelizable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit-3.0

I have implemented the following setup in my automation framework:

- C# Selenium webDriver
- IObjectContainer
- Specflow
- Nunit 3 Parallelizable
- Xpaths (and all selectors) are simply defined as 'private const string'

code sample HomePageSteps (working code):

```
[Binding]
    public class HomePageSteps
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        public HomePageSteps(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;
        }


        private const string LogoTwo = "//img[@alt='xpath']";

        [Given(@"I navigation to site")]
        public void GivenINavigationToSite()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://website.com/");

            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(LogoTwo)).Click();
        }
}
```

But I want to use the webDriver PageFactory attribute to handle my page objects. Which I have done / used in other projects that do Not use 'Nunit 3 Parallelizable'.

code example (NOT working code):

```
    [Binding]
    public class HomePageSteps
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        public HomePageSteps(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;
        }


        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//img[@alt='xpath']")]
        public IWebElement logo { get; set; }


        [Given(@"I navigation to site")]
        public void GivenINavigationToSite()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://website.com/");

            logo.Click();
        }
}
```

The problem here is that 'logo' is Null. And I'm not sure if this problem is related to a limitation of use ''Nunit 3 Parallelizable' with PageFactory, or with specflow, or something else in my design.

Can anyone please give some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The reason Page Factory would not initialize non-static driver is that it takes in Static driver. If The constructor for the page is defined like this :

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(startDirectory + @"\Drivers\", "chromedriver.exe");
    IWebDriver Static driver = new ChromeDriver(Service);
            public HomePageSteps()
            {
                PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
            }
```

It would allow you to use the elements as you have defined them.

Please let me know if you have found any other work around to this.